# How do I loop through column names and make a ggplot scatteplot for each one

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe `filter`, which is a subset of dataframe `df2`, which was made with dyplr's `mutate()` function.

I want to loop through some columns and make scatterplots with them.

My loop:

```
colNames <- names(filter)[9:47]
for(i in colNames){
  ggplot(filter, aes(x=i, y=CrimesPer10k)) +
    geom_point(color="#B20000", size=4, alpha=0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept=0, size=0.06, color="black") + 
    geom_smooth(method=lm, alpha=0.25, color="black", fill="black")
}
```

Yet I get no output, nor any errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to explicitly `print()` the object returned by `ggplot()` in a `for` loop because auto-`print()`ing is turned off there (and a few other places).

You also need to use `aes_string()` in place of `aes()` because you aren't using `i` as the actual variable in `filter` but as a character string containing the variable (in turn) in `filter` to be plotted.

Here is an example implementing both of these:

```
Y <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(A = rnorm(100), B = runif(100), C = rlnorm(100),
                 Y = Y)
colNames <- names(df)[1:3]
for(i in colNames){
  plt <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x=i, y = Y)) +
    geom_point(color="#B20000", size=4, alpha=0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept=0, size=0.06, color="black") + 
    geom_smooth(method=lm, alpha=0.25, color="black", fill="black")
  print(plt)
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

aes_string() was deprecated in ggplot2 > 3.0.0 but .data[[]] can be used.

```
colNames <- names(filter)[9:47]
for(i in colNames){
  plt <- ggplot(filter, aes(x=.data[[i]], y=CrimesPer10k)) +
    geom_point(color="#B20000", size=4, alpha=0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept=0, size=0.06, color="black") + 
    geom_smooth(method=lm, alpha=0.25, color="black", fill="black")
print(plt)
}
```