# Looping through columns with ggplot and modyfing geom_hline(yintercept) accordingly

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-hline

This is an incremental question that refers directly to this topic:

[How do I loop through column names and make a ggplot scatteplot for each one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425892/how-do-i-loop-through-column-names-and-make-a-ggplot-scatteplot-for-each-one)

I would like to loop through column names and make a ggplot scatteplot for each one, but I want add each time a horizintal line whose intercept depends on values in the column.

So I take that code:

```
Y <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(A = rnorm(100), B = runif(100), C = rlnorm(100),
                 Y = Y)
colNames <- names(df)[1:3]
for(i in colNames){
  plt <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x=i, y = Y)) +
    geom_point(color="#B20000", size=4, alpha=0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept=0, size=0.06, color="black") + 
    geom_smooth(method=lm, alpha=0.25, color="black", fill="black")
  print(plt)
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

I switch y with x

```
aes_string(x=Y, y = i))
```

and I want to to modify that line

```
geom_hline(yintercept=0, size=0.06, color="black")
```

...so that yintercept is not constant, but depends on i,
for example:

```
geom_hline(yintercept=c(quantile(i, 0.25)))
```

So that yintercept is always the first quartile of my column.

However, it doesnt work:

Error in (1 - h) * qs[i] :
non-numeric argument to binary operator

I tried different options such as aes_string, paste() etc
but none of this worked.

However, it doesnt work: Error in (1 - h) * qs[i] :
non-numeric argument to binary operator

I tried different options such as aes_string, paste() etc
but none of this worked.

Comment: Try `quantile(df[,i], 0.25)`

Answer (score 0):

You should call `quantile(df[,i], 0.25)` instead of `quantile(i, 0.25)` and it should work, your code would be :

```
for(i in colNames){
  plt <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x=Y, y = i)) +
    geom_point(color="#B20000", size=4, alpha=0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept=c(quantile(df[,i], 0.25)))+
    geom_smooth(method=lm, alpha=0.25, color="black", fill="black")
  print(plt)
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

Comment: if you want to substract this value for 1.5 IQR (and then calculate 1.5*IQR-q25) your formula should be `c( 1.5*IQR(df[,i])-quantile(df[,i], 0.25))`. In your code you do the opposite, and you forgot a parenthesis : quantile(df[,i], 0.25 **)** - 1.5*IQR(df[,i])