# Produce facet_wrap histograms for all numeric columns with faceting for another column in a 'for' loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, histogram

I would like to produce histograms with density lines for all my numeric columns, and facet them by another column.

Using the [Iris data set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set) as an example, I would like to produce histograms for `Sepal.Length`, etc., with facets for each of `Species`.

This is what I have tried:

```
for (i in colnames(subset(iris, select = -`Species`))) {
plot=  ggplot(iris, aes(x= i))+
    geom_histogram()+
    geom_density(colour = "blue", size = 1) +
    facet_wrap(~ Species, scales = "free")

 print(plot)
}
```

I also tried

```
for (i in colnames(subset(iris, select = -`Species`))) {
plot=  ggplot(subset(iris, select = -`Species`), aes(x= i))+
    geom_histogram()+
    geom_density(colour = "blue", size = 1) +
    facet_wrap(~ iris$Species, scales = "free")

 print(plot)
}
```

The error I get is

> Error in `f()`:
> StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?

Do I need to put something in the `geom_histogram()` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** OP request see comments:

```
library(tidyverse)
irislong= pivot_longer(iris, cols = -Species)  
ggplot(irislong, aes(x= value, fill= Species, alpha = 0.4))+   
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..))+   
  geom_density(colour = "blue", size = 1)+    
  facet_wrap(~ name, scales = "free")
```

[image]

**First answer:**
Here is one possible solution:

1. We bring the data in long format, with `pivot_longer`. Then apply `fill= name` and facet_wrap like you did:

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Species) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, fill=name))+
    geom_histogram() +
    geom_density(colour = "blue", size = 1) +
    facet_wrap(~ Species, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: this is very helpful. I originally wanted a separate plot for each variables, but this maybe more useful. I've now done this: `irislong= pivot_longer(iris, cols = -Species)

ggplot(irislong, aes(x= value, colour= Species))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..))+
  geom_density(colour = "blue", size = 1)+ 
  facet_wrap(~ name, scales = "free")` How can I get a separate`geom_density` line for each species?

Comment: Please see my update. By changing `colour` aesthetics with `fill` you might get your desired output!

Answer (score 0):

I found a helpful answer to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425892/how-do-i-loop-through-column-names-and-make-a-ggplot-scatteplot-for-each-one).
I needed to use `aes_string`.
This is what got the desired effect for my original question:

```
for (i in colnames(subset(iris, select = -`Species`))) {
plot=  ggplot(subset(iris, select = -`Species`), aes_string(x= i))+
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..))+
    geom_density(colour = "blue", size = 1)+ 
    facet_wrap(~ iris$Species, scales = "free")
  
 print(plot)
}
```

producing separate plots for each variable.

Comment: As tidyverse [docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html) indicate, `aes_string` is soft-deprecated among other aesthetic mappings. Instead use `.data` pronoun: `aes(.data[[i]])`.